# Is it possible to get the location of a specific color in an image using bash?

Tags: bash, image-processing

I have an image that is mostly white but has a red rectangle in it. Is there a way to find the coordinates of that red rectangle using bash?

Comment: By saying `bash` you mean the command line, not really the shell, or do you?

Comment: OpenCV can do [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use image-magick to work with the image. They also have a top notch forum, for any assistance you might need.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the contrast and variability of the pixels in the image. For the following example image you can simply ask ImageMagick's `convert` program to trim the background away, using an approximate *fuzzy* colour match, leaving just the "important" part, in this case the red rectangle:

```
convert findred.png -fuzz 30% -trim out.png
```

[image] results in [image]

To find the size and position of the resulting trimmed image, instead just pipe the output into ImageMagick's `identify` program (note the "-" for stdout and stdin).

```
convert findred.png -fuzz 30% -trim - | identify -
```

This prints

```
-=>/tmp/magick-... PNG 64x54 284x212+176+44  ...
```

where `176+44` is the x and y offset of the red rectangle in the original image, and `64x54` is the size of the resulting trimmed image.